# Database still in use after Connection.close()

Tags: java, javadb

When I connect to a database (whose location is provided by a JFileChooser), I check if the database is outdated, and if necessary, try to delete it and replace it.
The Error I get is the following:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\Users\User\Documents\POS-Data\Tables\seg0\cd1.dat
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2279)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:2270)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1653)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1535)
at Admin.SendReceiveData.SendData(SendReceiveData.java:226)
at Admin.SendReceiveData.SendAllBActionPerformed(SendReceiveData.java:183)
at Admin.SendReceiveData.access$100(SendReceiveData.java:13)
at Admin.SendReceiveData$3.actionPerformed(SendReceiveData.java:151)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3322)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I use the following URL:

```
String URL = "jdbc:derby:" + DestinationFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Tables;create=true;user=root;password=root";
```

Note that I always use Connection.close(), yet the database seems open until i close the program. This is preventing me from updating the database, any suggestion on how to completely release the database resources?

(System.gc won't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem:

```
DriverManager.getConnection(URL+";shutdown=true");
```

Will shutdown the database!

Answer (score 1):

Closing a connection to the database doesnt mean that the datatbe will close and release its resources - like file handles. You would need to close the databse first.

Moreover if you're running Derby embeded in your appliation - that it means that the database runs in the same JVM as your application. In that case aybe this [Shutting down by using the API](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.12/adminguide/index.html) will help you.